# Using fog with glOrtho

Tags: opengl

I'm using glOrtho to draw orthogonal projection of 3D geometric objects. My program allows the users to select edges or faces of the geometric object. When two objects appear on top of each other the user can select the background object with the right button, while the foreground object is selected with the left click. The selected object are colored.

The problem is that there is no way for the user to differentiate between a foreground or background selection. I tried using fog to make the color in the back look different from the one in the front, but that does not work. I'm guessing that this is because the z of the fore- and background are almost the same...? Is there still a way I could achieve that with a fog like function?

PS: I don't want to determine the position of the object (fore- vs. background) only when the user clicks since the object can be rotated and this information is then not correct anymore.

Comment: Before we go deeper, please specify: What do you mean "foreground object" and "background object"? Can you elaborate on that? Let me remind that at any time after rendering, the framebuffer at a given point contains the color value and the depth value of one fragment (which usually is the fragment which was the closest to the eye). And there could be any number of such fragments, so at a given (x,y) there could be an arbitrary number of objects.

Comment: I draw geometric objects. Imagine a cube for example. When you look at its projection, the foreground objects are the faces and edges that are close to you, while the background objects are typically the faces that are hidden. So for example, if you look at the cub from above so that the front and back faces are perfectly aligned, when you project it everything is superposed in two layers. Those are the layers I call fore and background. Does it make more sense?

Answer (score 1):

Could you not write a simple shader that will take the z-depth into account and colors a mesh using this value? For example using a ramp from one color for "foreground" objects to another for "background" objects?

Comment: Maybe? I'm not really familiar with shaders, how would the shader you suggest work?

Comment: Well, that depends a bit on how you would ideally differentiate between foreground and background objects. So if you have some specific "ideal situation" ideas on that, it could help to provide you with an answer.
However, the shader would basically do what I said. You take the z_depth into account and use this as input to color the different objects based on their distance from the viewer. Either on a ramp or with some other coloring function.

Comment: OK, but that basically means that I will be doing OpenGL's job by analyzing the z for everything I draw, while it must be possible to do it automatically. Or am I missing something?